# how to forced boostrap3 for another line if the space is not enough?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a text(with no space) that is long for the div with a class of "col-md-3". it is long that it look like it was floating to the other div. i can't just put space cause it is an email add if it is viewed with another mobile it is just fine.

here is the sample

```
<div class="col-md-3">text with space</div><br/>
<div class="col-md-6">text with space again</div><br/>
<div class="col-md-3">verylongtextwithnospaceinbetween@somthinghere.com</div>
```

is there a class or property that will forced the text to break and have another line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's CSS property for this: word-break.

if you need to make it work on old browsers too the complete usage, with vendor prefixes, is:

```
.col-md-3{
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-all;

     // Non standard for webkit
     word-break: break-word;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
}
```

source: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

Comment: i've tried and i worked fine...i accept this as the answer and vote it later as soon as i will have a reputation to do so...many thanks...